# Why Firebase Crash Reporting is too much slow?

Tags: firebase, splunk, firebase-crash-reporting

So far in Android application development, I've used many more analytics and crashing report tools as well.

1. [Flurry](https://dev.flurry.com/)
2. [Mint](http://mint.splunk.com)
3. [Firebase Crash Reporting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/)

My observation are below,

1. For flurry it was first time to test what is crash reporting tools in android , and that time i got a crash report not in real time.
2. Perfect, It is really smooth and fast reporting tools.
3. In my case crashing report timing are likely

Flurry > Firrebase > Mint Splunk

Now come to my point, there crashing report is almost the same, but in [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/), I got some extra information rater then other crash reporting tools.

[image]

My question is, how can I improve my current crash reporing time significantly in Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't improve the time it takes for a backend service to do what it needs to do to process a crash.  Firebase Crash Reporting generally shows crashes within a minute of them being reported.  There may be temporary delays, and you can't control that.  Sometimes the crash report can't be sent by the time the app process dies, in which case, the error won't have another chance to be reported until the app is restarted.